# While loop not working properly for even/idd numbers

Tags: java, while-loop, set

My assignment is to create a method that returns true if my set of integers has an un-even number in it. My problem is that even if I have un-even numbers in my set, it will return false. Where am i making a mistake?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Chapter_11_E9
{   


    public static boolean odd;
    public static boolean hasOdd(Set<Integer> tSet1)
    {
        Iterator<Integer> itr = tSet1.iterator();

            while (itr.hasNext())
            {
                int current = itr.next();
                if ((current / 2) == 1)
                {
                    odd = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    odd = false;
                }
            }
        return odd;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Set<Integer> tSet1 = new HashSet<Integer>();
        tSet1.add(6);
        tSet1.add(2);
        tSet1.add(5);
        tSet1.add(4);
        tSet1.add(12);
        tSet1.add(6);
        tSet1.add(14);
        System.out.println(tSet1);      
        System.out.println(hasOdd(tSet1));
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) There is no need to add the major tag in the title. 2) Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
        if ((current / 2) == 1)
```

Should be:

```
        if ((current % 2) == 1)
```

`/` is for diving and `%` is for getting the remainder.  Also, your method logic is off.  Say you have multiple odds and evens in the set, you could get wrong results.  I'd recommend doing this:

```
public static boolean hasOdd(Set<Integer> tSet1)
{
    Iterator<Integer> itr = tSet1.iterator();

        while (itr.hasNext())
        {
            int current = itr.next();
            if ((current % 2) == 1)
            {
                //odd = true;
                return true;//once you find the odd, just return
            }
            //else
            //{
            //    odd = false;
            //}
        }
    //return odd;
    //if you're done iterating, that means it never found an odd so return false
    return false;
}
```

Once you've found one odd in the set, then your case is true.  Once you've looped through the entire set, then you know there could haven't been any odds, so just return false.

**Note**:  As user ***ZouZou*** mentioned, if you want to handle negatives, then use:

```
current%2 != 0
```

Comment: Always prefer `current%2 != 0`, because if the number is odd and negative, that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the first time you get an odd value (as is you'll only return true if the last item is odd).

```
public static boolean hasOdd(Set<Integer> tSet1)
{
  Iterator<Integer> itr = tSet1.iterator();
  while (itr.hasNext())
  {
    int current = itr.next();
    if ((current % 2) != 0) // Check for odd, by computing the modulo 2 of the #.
    {
      return true;          // stop, there is an odd value.
    }
  }
  return false;             // checked all the values... none are odd.
}
```

Comment: I would definitely use `%` over `&` here. Optimizing for speed over readability seems very wrong for this task.

Answer (score 0):

I would use for-each loop here

```
public static boolean hasOdd(Set<Integer> set) {
  for (Integer current : set) {
    // Check for odd, by computing the modulo 2 of the #.
    if ((current % 2) != 0) {
      // stop, there is an odd value.
      return true;
    }
  }
  // checked all the values... none are odd.
  return false;
}
```